# Symfony HTTP Cache doesn't work in 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I've tested code form [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/http_cache.html) in Symfony 3.2 and it was everything good, but cache doesn't work in 3.4.8.

Of courese I want to use Symfony Reverse Proxy.

My `app_dev.php`

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
    $kernel->loadClassCache();
}
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
```

My action look's like this:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    // [...]
    $response = $this->render('base.html.twig');

    $response->setSharedMaxAge(3600);

        return $response;
}
```

Am I missing something, that isn't nessesery in Symfony 3.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it's imposible, by some Symfony 3.4 bug. I used Symfony Cache Component instead https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony decided to **deprecate** the entire ClassLoader component for Symfony 3.3+.

In this case line below is no longer available

```
$kernel->loadClassCache(); // deprecated
```

In this case you should use class loader provided by Composer. If you are not using PHP 7.0 yet, you should stay with Symfony 3.2.

---

**Useful links**

[New in Symfony 3.3: Deprecated the ClassLoader component](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-deprecated-the-classloader-component)

[Autoloader Optimization](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md)

Comment: This statement is completely wrong. "deprecated" does not mean it "is no longer available" nor that it does not work. It work perfectly fine in both 3.3 and 3.4. It means it is not available in 4.0 which is not the case here. Compare [3.2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php#L328) to [3.4](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php)

Comment: That's right, in addition HTTP Cache still doesn't work.