# Symfony HTTP Cache-Control header overriding

Tags: symfony, http, caching, cache-control

I've answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011465/symfony-http-cache-doesnt-work-in-3-4) question some time ago.

My code at the moment in Symfony 3.4.

```
 $response->setCache([
     'max_age' => 3600,
     'public' => true,
     's_maxage' => 3600,
 ]);


 // (optional) set a custom Cache-Control directive
 $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);

 return $response;
```

In some reason I'm still getting `Cache-Control` and other headers like this:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private, s-maxage=3600
X-Symfony-Cache: GET /: miss
```

I've noticed that in Symfony 3.2 code works well, but  in 3.4 I'm not getting `public` in Cache-Control (and `max-age=0` looks bad too).

Second thing is dumping `$response` in controller - everything looks fine:

```
#headers: array:2 [▼
  "cache-control" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "max-age=3600, must-revalidate, public, s-maxage=3600"
  ]
  "date" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "Sat, 12 May 2018 18:42:04 GMT"
  ]
]
```

Is it somekind of Symfony bug? Should I report it?

Comment: Same problem here, still wondering why this happen.

Comment: Theres a workaround for Symfony 3.4 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52846748/597060

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same with Symfony 3.4.14. And spent 5 hours to find out that
since 3.4 version symfony overrides Cache-Control header if session exists ([4.1 documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache.html#http-caching-and-user-sessions)).

Symfony 3.4 documentation does not have this info.

Comment: In 4.1 you can disable this behaviour with `$response->headers->set(AbstractSessionListener::NO_AUTO_CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER, 'true');`

Comment: Just stumbled upon this answer, thank you for saving me hours of debugging! Do you know of any nice way to disable this behaviour in 3.4? Not found a way to write a custom SessionListener yet.

Comment: @Nick unfortunately not:( I had to use redis for sql-results caching and also used decorators for services to cache results

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I used the symfony/security-bundle which came with a default configuration:

```
security:
    providers:
     ....
    firewalls:
        main:
          anonymous: true
```

This code initialise a session. You may want to use :

```
security:
    providers:
     ....
    firewalls:
        main:
          security: false
```