# Symfony 3.4 http cache , always Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private

Tags: symfony, caching, foshttpcachebundle

I try in annotation

```
 * @Cache(expires="+10 hours", public=false)
```

or in controller

```
$maxAge = 60*60;
$response->setExpires(Carbon::create()->addHour());
$response->setSharedMaxAge($maxAge);
$response->setPublic();
$response->setMaxAge($maxAge);
```

And still have `Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private`

App use sessions, user is login - I want - cache private, but nothing work - I always get this.

I've added `FOS\HttpCacheBundle\FOSHttpCacheBundle()`

(just add) Have hope to it override symfony cache and allow send cache private - but nothing change.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This behaviour is new as of Symfony 3.4 and 4.0. If a user session has been initialized it will always set the headers as described in your question.

Introduced in Symfony 4.1 you can override this behaviour. However as this is a new feature this will not be backported to Symfony 3.4.

```
$response->headers->set(AbstractSessionListener::NO_AUTO_CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER, 'true');
```

You can read about this in the Symfony documentation: [HTTP Caching and User Sessions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache.html#http-caching-and-user-sessions)

Comment: Am I reading this wrong, or this means that in v3.4, it is not possible to use the ESI with HTTP Cache, as long as you have an active user session?

Comment: Apparently you are reading it right. This is a non-trivial B/C break for ESI-based setups, one can even not cache responses that are user-agnostic when session cookie exists (regardless of the actual login state).

Bug report: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29151

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best way to do this would be to use [Service decoration](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/service_decoration.html), but i prefered the dirty way for now.

In my case i just needed the shared cached headers for a specific controller.

Workaroung for Symfony 3.4.*:

Create a listener with lower priority than `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener` in `services.yml` (don't know if this is recommended):

```
AppBundle\Listener\ResponseListener:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, priority: -1001 }
```

Then in `AppBundle\Listener\ResponseListener`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class ResponseListener
{
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $response = $event->getResponse();

        $controller = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller');
        $requiredAssetAction = "AppBundle\Controller\Website\AssetsController::assetAction";

        if ($controller == $requiredAssetAction) {
            $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('max-age', 900);
            $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('s-maxage', 900);
            $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
            $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('public', true);
            $response->headers->removeCacheControlDirective('private');

        }

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! You can apply the changes to a whole controller using `if (strpos($controller, 'AssetController') !== false)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a reverse proxy like the Symfony one?
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/http_cache.html#symfony-reverse-proxy

Also, in your example, the annotation has public=false while the controller will have public true.

Another possible problem would be that your webserver (Apatche etc) is configured to add that header or an option in your .htaccess file specifies this.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this in a legacy 3.4 application by simply implementing the logic from the `AbstractSessionListener` and `SessionListener` classes from the `symfony/http-kernel` component in my own listener and overwriting the service with an alias to my own implementation:

```
  session_listener:
    alias: 'Vendored\Symfony\EventSubscriber\SessionListener'
    tags:
      - { name: 'kernel.event_subscriber' }
```